# Find the probability that: a) the second ball is red b) the second ball is red, given that the first is red.

Tags: probability

There are $n$ bins of which the $k$th contains $k-1$ blue and $n-k$ red balls.You pick a bin at random and remove two balls at random without replacement.
Find the probability that:
a) the second ball is red
b) the second ball is red, given that the first is red.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions. Please add how you attempted to solve the problem or how stumbled upon this question.

Comment: What do you know about [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)?  About the multiplication principle of probability?  If you picked the $k^{th}$ bin and picked a single ball, what is the chance that you picked a red ball?